# basic Tcl -- printing a value of variable

Tags: set, tcl, puts

I have the following script in Tcl:

```
set val(a) 10
set val(b) 10
set val(n) expr{$val(a) * $val(b)}
```

How to print the value of the variable n?

```
puts $val(n)
```

gives  `expr{10*10}`  and i need to see 100....

Answer (score 8):

In order to evaluate an expression and return the results, you must put the `eval` command inside square brackets, rather than try to call it like a function:

```
set val(n) [expr {$val(a) * $val(b)}]
puts $val(n)
```

Comment: Any reason for the curly brackets?

Comment: @user828193 Yes, it allows Tcl to compile the expression rather than reparsing it each time through. It also avoids a number of hazards (such as if someone puts `[exit]` in the `val(a)` variable).